# Can you pass compiler flags to dart2js via Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

I want to run a no minify build but not from Terminal. Can I do it form the Dart Editor IDE itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart2JS can be configured using pubspec.yaml [Configuring the Built-in dart2js Transformer.](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html)
You also need a custom launch configuration until DartEditor's internal web server is replaced by `pub serve` which is work in progress.

Comment: "You also need a custom launch configuration" - Sorry, what do you mean? Where do I need to do my custom launch config?

Answer (score 6):

Under Run -> Manage Launches you can create a new Dart2js launch and pass in whatever compiler flags you want.