# Is it possible to configure `pub build` so that it does not suppress hints and warnings?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart2js

I'm trying to **not** get messages like this when I run `pub build`:

```
WARN: [Dart2JS on mylib|web/mylib.dart]:  
    | 1 warning(s) and 2 hint(s) suppressed in package:otherlib.  
WARN: [Dart2JS on pinged|web/mylib.dart]:   
    | 2 warning(s) suppressed in package:mylib.  
WARN: [Warning from Dart2JS on mylib|web/mylib.dart]:  
    | 1 hint(s) suppressed in package:mypackage.  
WARN: [Warning from Dart2JS on pinged|web/mylib.dart]:  
    | 1 hint(s) suppressed in package:otherpackage.
```

I've tried building with `pub build --verbose --trace` and adding `--verbose` to my $dart2js transformer commandLineOptions in pubspec.yaml.

It seems that, by default, dart2js does **not** suppress hints and warnings (hence the `--suppress-warnings` and `--suppress-hints` options), but the `pub build` "wrapper" around dart2js changes these defaults and gives you no real way to enable verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

```
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--show-package-warnings]
```

see also:

[Can you pass compiler flags to dart2js via Dart Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054960/can-you-pass-compiler-flags-to-dart2js-via-dart-editor/22059684#22059684)

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html

Comment: Upvoted -- thank you. This gives me verbose warnings, though it seems to completely suppress hints now, and I don't even get counts for those (on the 1.8.3 SDK anyway).

Comment: Since you can pass command line options via `$dart2js`, can you also pass `--surpress-warnings` ?